# Jquery Not Working on anonymous function call with ID selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to run Alert function on page load using jquery but it's not working for me.

Please let me know if I am wrong somewhere thanks.

Here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#alertcall').load(function(d){
        alert("Image loaded.");
    })(document);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="alertcall"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you are doing, so you are trying to get jQuery to output an alert? Perhaps this will work.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="alertcall"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#alertcall').load(function(d){
        alert("Div loaded");
    })(document);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want it to work with jQuery("#alertcall") . that is if there is no <div id="alertcall"></div> on any HTML page than I don't want alert on that page

Comment: Sure, have you tried using the load method (see updated answer).

Comment: Strange, can I see your full code (update your answer above) and I will try to figure it out.

Comment: Updated my question, try it on W3Schools editor your previous version was working there.

Comment: Ok I did some reading, it is not possible to fire a load event for an element such as a div. You can only do this for images or scripts. If you put your javascript directly below the div you want to wait for you can ensure the javascript will not be fired until the div is loaded. (see updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. You can check whether the element with id alertcall exists or not.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  if($('#alertcall').length){
    alert("image loaded");
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to perform some action when image loads. Use image instead of div.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myImage').load(function(d) {
    alert("Image loaded.");
  });
}); < /script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <img id="myImage" src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/high-resolution-wallpapers-2.jpg" alt="high resolution image">


</body>

</html>
```

Change image URL to test again to avoid cached image

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myImage').load(function(d) {
    alert("Image loaded.");
  });
}); < /script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <img id="myImage" src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/high-resolution-wallpapers-2.jpg" alt="high resolution image">


</body>

</html>
```